# Break the iteration and got the values and states?

Tags: f#

I need to call a function on each item in the list; and quit immediately if the function returns -1. I need to return the sum of results of the function and a string of "Done" or "Error".

```
let input = seq { 0..4 } // fake input

let calc1 x = // mimic failing after input 3. It's a very expensive function and should stop running after failing
    if x >= 3 then -1 else x * 2

let run input calc = 
    input 
    |> Seq.map(fun x -> 
        let v = calc x
        if v = -1 then .... // Error occurred, stop the execution if gets -1. Calc will not work anymore
        v)
     |> Seq.sum, if hasError then "Error" else "Done"  

run input calc // should return (6, "Error")
run input id   // should return (20, "Done")
```

Comment: I'm not clear on this point.  Are the calculations totally independent, and thus a negative result on one doesn't impact the others or are they supposed to be sequential, and you need to quit after the first negative result?  It looks like the latter, but your use of Seq.map seems to imply the former.

Comment: The negative value is just used to mimic the occurring of the exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to *effectively* achieve exactly what is asked in idiomatic manner would be to use of an inner recursive function for traversing the sequence:

```
let run input calc =
    let rec inner unprocessed sum =
        match unprocessed with
        | [] -> (sum, "Done")
        | x::xs -> let res = calc x
                   if res < 0 then (sum, "Error") else inner xs (sum + res)
    inner (input |> Seq.toList) 0
```

Then `run (seq {0..4})  (fun x -> if x >=3 then -1 else x * 2)` returns `(6,"Error")` while
`run (seq [0;1;2;1;0;0;1;1;2;2])  (fun x -> if x >=3 then -1 else x * 2)` returns `(20, "Done")`

Comment: Whoops, I had forgotten about that last part in my answer.  I'm gonna go update it right now...

Comment: Is the function `inner` tail recursive?

Comment: @ca9163d9 - Yes, it is. A function is tail recursive if (and only if) at every point at which it calls itself, that return value of the "child" call immediately becomes the return value of the "parent" call, with no extra computation steps. The only place where `inner` calls itself is in that `else` block, and when it calls itself, that is the *last* operation in the parent function. In other words, the call is in "tail position", which is where the term tail-recursive comes from.

Comment: @rmunn but `if then else` is an expression in F# so the calling of `inner` is not the last operation? The last operation is `if res < 0 then (sum, "Error") else inner xs (sum + res)`?

Comment: @ca9163d9 - In `if A then B else C`, both B and C are final operations. If A is true, then the result of the function will be B. If A is false, then the result of the function will be C. So if either B or C is a function call, if they are called then their result *will* be the result of the parent function. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-f/ for more details.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - Though note that in that `if A then B else C`, the expression A is *not* a final operation, because either B or C is going to follow after A is calculated.

Answer (score 3):

More efficient version of the same thing shown below.  This means it is now essentially a copy of @GeneBelitski's answer.

```
let run input calc = 
    let inputList = Seq.toList input
    let rec subrun inp acc = 
        match inp with
        | [] -> (acc, "Done")
        | (x :: xs) -> 
            let res = calc x
            match res with
            | Some(y) -> subrun xs (acc + y)
            | None -> (acc, "Error")
    subrun inputList 0
```

---

Note that this function below is EXTREMELY slow, likely because it uses Seq.tail (I had thought that would be the same as List.tail).  I leave it in for posterity.

The easiest way I can think of for doing this in F# would be to use a tail-recursive function.  Something like

```
let run input calc = 
    let rec subrun inp acc = 
        if Seq.isEmpty inp then
            (acc, "Done")
        else
            let res = calc (Seq.head inp)
            match res with
            | Some(x) -> subrun (Seq.tail inp) (acc + x)
            | None -> (acc, "Error")
    subrun input 0
```

I'm not 100% sure just how efficient that would be.  In my experience, sometimes for some reason, my own tail-recursive functions seem to be considerably slower than using the built-in higher-order functions.  This should at least get you to the right result.

---

*The below, while apparently not answering the actual question, is left in just in case it is useful to someone.*

The typical way to handle this would be to make your calc function return either an Option or Result type, e.g.

```
let calc1 x = if x = 3 then None else Some(x*2)
```

and then map that to your input.  Afterwards, you can fairly easily do something like

```
|> Seq.exists Option.isNone
```

to make see if there are Nones in the resulting seq (you can pipe it to not if you want the opposite result).

If you just need to eliminate Nones from the list, you can use

```
Seq.choose id
```

which will eliminate all Nones while leaving the Options intact.

For summing the list, assuming that you have used choose to be left with just the Somes, then you can do

```
Seq.sumBy Option.get
```

Comment: The calc will fail for all subsequently execution. So it's not that simple. I know it can be done easily using a mutable variable.

Comment: @ca9163d9 updated the answer to better reflect what you seem to be asking for.

Comment: @Jarak: when I placed my answer and noticed your edit, my first move was deleting my answer, but then I reread your edit and noticed something that caused me to undelete mine

Comment: @GeneBelitski Yeah, don't delete your answer!  I don't think it would hurt to have two.  Out of curiosity, what was the part you noticed?    Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @Jarak: I *definitely* will not. Try to run with timing mine and yours variants with let's say a sequence of 1000 ones: on my box mine takes 7ms to complete, while yours - around 4.5sec. You should feel the pain :) And the cause of such dramatic slowdown I guess is your use of `Seq.tail` in traversing.

Comment: @GeneBelitski Ah yes, you're quite right.  I was trying to keep the collection as a Seq, but it seems clear that Seq.tail is VERY slow - I had assumed it would essentially be exactly the same as List.tail...  This would explain why some of my other tail recursive functions seemed to be so slow.  I'm gonna update my answer again, which means that it'll basically be a copy of yours now.

Comment: @Jarak: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42913180/917053) you can find a great explanation on `Seq.tail` associated dangers when it used without a due caution.

Comment: @GeneBelitski Thanks for that!  :) Turns out Seq.tail works _very_ differently to what I had believed...  I came here trying to answer a question and ended up learning something important myself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a monadic way of doing it using the `Result` monad.

First we create function `calcR` that if `calc` returns -1 returns `Error` otherwise returns `Ok` with the value:

```
let calcR f x = 
    let r = f x
    if  r = -1 then Error "result was = -1" else
    Ok  r
```

Then, we create function `sumWhileOk` that uses `Seq.fold` over the input, adding up the results as long as they are `Ok`.

```
let sumWhileOk fR = 
    Seq.fold(fun totalR v -> 
        totalR 
        |> Result.bind(fun total -> 
            fR v 
            |> Result.map      (fun r -> total + r) 
            |> Result.mapError (fun _ -> total    )
        ) 
    ) (Ok 0)
```

`Result.bind` and `Result.map` only invoke their lambda function if the supplied value is `Ok` if it is  `Error` it gets bypassed. `Result.mapError` is used to replace the error message from `calcR` with the current total as an error.

It is called this way:

```
input |> sumWhileOk (calcR id)
// returns: Ok 10

input |> sumWhileOk (calcR calc1)
// return:  Error 6
```